# How to "and" operator for all elements of list?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

i have the books with different tags (crime, fantastic, dramatic etc.).
that's my sql-code:

```
query := `
    SELECT gotoboox.books.id, gotoboox.books.title 
    FROM gotoboox.books 
    LEFT JOIN gotoboox.books_tags ON gotoboox.books.id = gotoboox.books_tags.book_id 
    LEFT JOIN gotoboox.tags ON gotoboox.books_tags.tag_id = gotoboox.tags.id 
    WHERE gotoboox.tags.title IN ($1) 
    GROUP BY gotoboox.books.title, gotoboox.books.id
`
rows, err := p.Db.Query(query, pq.Array(tags))
```

but i have got empty result.
for example, if i write

```
..WHERE gotoboox.tags.title IN ('Crime', 'Comedia').. // WITHOUT pg.Array()
```

its okay.

so, i need pass correctly my pq.Array(tags) to the 'where in'-statement.

**P.S.** tags is a slice of strings. "tags []string"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Please don't post images of text — include the text as text.  For tables like the one in the first image (I've not looked at the others), copy'n'paste the text into the SO editor window, then select it, and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it as code.  (The icing on the cake is to put a line `<!-- language: lang-none -->` on a line on its own with a blank line before and after to avoid the table being marked up as text.  That is entirely optional, though.)

Comment: Your question is entirely unreadable, due to the images of text. Copy and paste the _relevant_ text directly into the question instead.

Comment: edited. pls, read again it :)

Comment: @peterSO, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
gotoboox.tags.title IN ('Crime', 'Comedia')
```

is, more or less, a short way to write:

```
gotoboox.tags.title = 'Crime' or gotoboox.tags.title = 'Comedia'
```

so you don't want to supply an array for the placeholder in `IN ($1)` unless `tags.title` is itself an array (which it isn't).

If you want to pass a slice for the placeholder and use `pq.Array`, you want to use [`= ANY(array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#id-1.5.8.28.16) in the SQL:

```
query := `... WHERE gotoboox.tags.title = any ($1) ...`
rows, err := p.Db.Query(query, pq.Array(tags))
```

Alternatively, if `tags` had `n` elements then you could build a string like:

```
"$1,$2,...,$n"
```

`fmt.Sprintf` that into your SQL (which is perfectly safe since you know exactly what's in the strings):

```
p := placeholders(len(tags))
q := fmt.Sprintf("select ... where gotoboox.tags.title in (%s) ...", p)
```

and then supply values for all those placeholders when you query:

```
rows, err := p.DB.Query(q, tags...)
```

Comment: wow, it's almost solved my problem. but now, i have the list of books, each of which have NOT ALL selected tags, but at least 1.
i need books with ALL selected tags)

Comment: The usual approach is to add a `having count(*) = length_of_tags` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Below query will results in books with all selected tags.

```
select 
  b.id, 
  b.title 
from 
  books b 
  join books_tags bt on bt.book_id = b.id 
  join tags t on bt.tag_id = t.id 
where 
  t.title = any($1) 
group by 
  b.id, 
  b.title 
having 
  count(*)= cardinality($1)
```